# Comparing Image.Source

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

In WinRT app I have 2 different images but with the same source:

```
 <Image Name="image1" Source="mySource.png"/>
 <Image Name="image2" Source="mySource.png"/>
```

When I compare image1.Source with image2.Source it returns false . How to compare Sources so as to get true if they show the same picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to cast the `Source` objects as bitmaps. Then you can compare the `AbsoluteUri`:

```
BitmapImage bm1 = (BitmapImage)image1.Source;
BitmapImage bm2 = (BitmapImage)image2.Source;

bool same = 
    (string.Compare(bm1.UriSource.AbsoluteUri, bm2.UriSource.AbsoluteUri) == 0);
```